# Add Outlook attachment by reference to Sharepoint document

Tags: c#, sharepoint, outlook

I am trying to add a reference to a document located in a sharepoint library as an attachment to Outlook email. I got the following error:

> File name or directory name is not
>   valid.

I used this code:

```
String sSource = "http://lu3:333/TestList/Doc.txt ";
String sDisplayName = att.DisplayName;
int iPosition = (int)mail.Body.Length + 1;
int iAttachType = (int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByReference;
mail.Attachments.Add(sSource, iAttachType, iPosition, sDisplayName);
```

When i use the *OlAttachmentType.olByValue* it works but by reference it is not.

Anyone have an idea how to fix this? Or is there a better solution to add a reference to a document located in sharepoint site as an attachment?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to download it locally first. Then you can attach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would be better off formatting an html message and link to the file using either an a tag or an image link.

There may be reasons to send an actual attachment, but I would argue against them strongly if possible.

Comment: I ended up creating an html attachment.